# Can both terms be used? Dated and Scheduled

Tags: terminology, usage

Is it okay to use both dated and scheduled when informing an event is to be held on a specific date?
ex)

- The match is dated on 1st of February
- The match is scheduled on 1st of February

Answer (score 4):

***Dated*** does not mean planned for a particular date. It means:

1. provided with a date

> - e.g. a signed and dated painting ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01lwEndA4w1Dn7HtiZcAUZGOzrdbg%3A1612150617543&source=hp&ei=WXcXYLDVHs6MlwTh27GIDw&q=dated%20meaning&oq=dated&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIIxAnMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIILjICCAAyAggAOggIABCxAxCDAToLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxAzoECC4QJzoLCAAQsQMQgwEQkQI6CAguELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOggIABCxAxCLAzoLCAAQsQMQgwEQiwNQ5QRY6glg3hZoAHAAeACAAfYBiAGmBZIBBTIuMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpergBAg&sclient=psy-ab))

or

2. OUTMODED, OLD-FASHIONED

> - dated formalities ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dated))

When used with the first meaning, it does not take the preposition ***on***, and so your first sentence is not correct. Consider this example from [the New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2005/09/19/the-lost-city-of-z):

> The document was ***dated April 13, 1924*** and, unlike most of the other letters, it was typed, though Fawcett's small, slanting signature was visible at the bottom.

Your second sentence is awkward because of the preposition ***on***. I would understand "The match is scheduled on 1st of February" as "The scheduling of the match took place on 1st of February". If you mean that the match will take place on 1st of February, the expression to use is ***schedule for***:

> to arrange that an event or activity will happen at a particular time [or on a particular date]:
>
> - The meeting has been ***scheduled for*** tomorrow afternoon. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/schedule))

So the correct sentence would be:

> The match is ***scheduled for*** 1st of February.

Comment: Thank you so much! Understood clearly